# Does NASA's Titan explorer Dragonfly have a microscope? How will it observe potential microbial life?

Tags: nasa, astrobiology, titan, dragonfly, microscope

One of NASA's [stated goals](https://www.nasa.gov/dragonfly/frequently-asked-questions/index.html) with the Dragonfly mission is to "study astrobiology, prebiological chemistry, and the potential habitability of an extraterrestrial environment."

I would think it would be useful to directly observe environmental samples at a microscopic level to search for examples of living or dead organisms. When viewing their [instrument suite](https://www.nasa.gov/dragonfly/frequently-asked-questions/index.html) however, I see them mention:

> a mass spectrometer (Dragonfly Mass Spectrometer or DraMS) to identify chemical components relevant to astrobiology [...] and a variety of cameras (DragonCam) to image Titan’s terrain and help Dragonfly navigate and determine landing areas of scientific interest.

It doesn't seem to me that they have a microscope. Is this correct, and if so, how do they plan to detect and observe microbial life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that studying "*the potential habitability of an extraterrestrial environment*" does not necessarily mean "*detect and observe microbial life*".

However, Dragonfly appears to have not one but two microscopic cameras in its DragonCam suite (emphasis added):

> Dragonfly carries eight scientific cameras: two panorama cameras attached to the high-gain antenna for pointing, two fixed forward-looking cameras, two wide-angle downward-looking workspace cameras boresighted on the left and right sampling sites, and **two microscopic cameras with 60 μm pixels focused on the samples to be ingested**

From [Jason W. Barnes et al. "Science Goals and Objectives for the Dragonfly Titan Rotorcraft Relocatable Lander," 2021 Planet. Sci. J. 2 130](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/PSJ/abfdcf)

For reference [Perseverance's PIXL micro-context camera (MCC)](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/m2020/urn-nasa-pds-mars2020_pixl/document/pixl_user_guide.pdf) ([raw images](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/)) has ~50 $\mu$m per pixel scale.